# WebAPI in VS 2010, method not returning JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating WebAPI using VS2010. I was following tutorial from [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) link.
So far I got everything working, but when I try to call my WebAPI method, instead of getting JSON array of objects, I'm getting just type name for this array.

Do I have to add anything else which is not mentioned in this tutorial to get this method returning JSON as it should?

EDIT: I have tried calling WebAPI method just as it was described in linked tutorial, by directly typing URL in address bar. I get same results in IE, FireFox and Chrome. When I set up breakpoint in my WebAPI method, it gets hit, my objects are properly created and method returns them, but I'm getting plain TypeName as output in browser (e.g. SomeNamespace.SomeClass[]).

I have tried using fiddler and changing "Accept" header to application/json in Composer, but with no luck.

I tried using Cassini and IISExpress but behavior is still the same.

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question.  Show the response you are getting.  Tell us what client you are using.  Chances are you are using a browser that is sending application/xml in the accept header.  But that's just a wild guess because you haven't given us anything to work with.

Comment: ...and to those who downvoted.  Downvoting without explaining what the problem is just makes the OP take it personally.  Please, don't do it.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details, but I do not understand why downvotes anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out what was wrong. When creating my controller I didn't choose "Empty API controller" option (facepalm). After I have changed my controller to derive from ApiController class everything was working properly.